# Where did /usr/local/git come from?

Tags: git

Because /usr/local/bin is ahead of /usr/bin in my path, I'm picking up the wrong version of git, and XCode is very unhappy.

Instead of manually blowing away /usr/local/git, I'd like to uninstall it properly using whatever package manager originally installed it. I'm pretty sure it wasn't homebrew

Comment: Why are you sure it wasn't homebrew?  You either used homebrew, macports, the download from git-scm.org, or you built it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To remove, if you installed via homebrew, run this command:

```
brew uninstall git
```

If you installed via macports do this command:

```
sudo port uninstall git
```

Otherwise, you installed via downloading a package or compiled yourself. Just manually remove:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/etc/gitconfig /usr/local/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git-cvsserver \
        /usr/local/bin/git-receive-pack /usr/local/bin/git-shell \
        /usr/local/bin/git-upload-archive /usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack \
        /usr/local/bin/scalar
```

Comment: It won't be macports as that leaves /usr/local alone . One reason it does that is exactly this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've never used macports on this machine. Homebrew disclaims any knowledge of git. For now, I've done `mkdir /usr/local/bin.bak; mv /usr/local/bin/git* /usr/local/bin.bak`. If I don't find out what package installed that stuff, I'll go ahead and just delete it.

Comment: If you installed the macOS download from git-scm.org, it has an uninstaller.  What you've been leaving out is what VERSION of git this is, which would help determine where it came from.